# Finding a key inside a nested dictionary with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Ditionary:

```
data = {
    "president": {
        "name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox",
        "species": "Betelgeusian"
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is return if a key named "name" exists.

```
if 'president' in data and 'name' in data['president']:
    print("found")
```

This works fine but only if I have pre knowledge of the dictionary's structure. Is there a way of knowing if there's a subkey called "name" recursively? I only found how to do this for the top level.

Comment: This is worth checking out : https://pypi.org/project/dictsearch/

Answer (score 2):

You can do a recursive search:

```
data = {
    "president": {
        "name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox",
        "species": "Betelgeusian"
    }
}

def r_find(target, key):
    if key in target:
        return True
    else:
        for k, v in target.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                if r_find(v, key):
                    return True
        return False


print(r_find(data, "name"))
print(r_find(data, "species"))
print(r_find(data, "no-name"))
```

**Output**

```
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a recursive generator with `try` / `except`:

```
def recursive_keys(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        try:
            yield from recursive_keys(v)
        except AttributeError:
            yield k

'name' in set(recursive_keys(data))  # True
```

If you prefer, you can use `isinstance` instead:

```
def recursive_keys(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from recursive_keys(v)
        else:
            yield k
```

This is relatively expensive, since you are first creating a `set` of all keys before checking if an item exists in the `set`. As per @pault's comment, you can use:

```
any(x == 'name' for x in recursive_keys(data))
```

For a lazy solution without generators, see [@DanielMesejo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52010656/9209546). This may be more efficient since it avoids expensive `__next__` calls.

Comment: How does the generator work here? Don't you need to build the whole set first to check the `in` condition? Wouldn't it be faster to return early as in @DanielMesejo's solution? Or maybe use `any(x == 'name' for x in recursive_keys(data))`?

Comment: @pault, Yep, I realised this a moment ago and added a recursive function which returns `True` when it finds a match.

Comment: but what about using `any` with a generator (as in my edited original comment)? Won't that realize the speed up of the generator because of short-circuiting?

Comment: @pault, Yes, good point. I think Daniel's solution would be faster (generator expressions can be slower), but yeh that's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a <strike>hacky</strike> non-traditional way would be to convert your `dict` to a string using `json.dumps`. Then you can search for the key as in the string.

For example:

```
import json 

def find_key(d, key):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return False
    else:
        return '"'+key+'": ' in json.dumps(d)

print(find_key(data, 'name'))
#True
```

One limitation is that this won't work if you can have `"name: "` inside one of your values.